# ng-show doesn't change on routeChange in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am developing an website with AngularJS and 
[mobile angular UI](http://mobileangularui.com/).

I have a menu bar which will show on clicking a button and should be closed when I click the options in it. But it isn't working as expected.

My files:

*index.html*

```
<div id="menuBar" ng-show="showMenu">
    <div class="row"> 
        <a href="#/page1"> page1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

*js* for hiding menu

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($rootScope, $scope) {

  $rootScope.showMenu = false;

  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function () {
      $rootScope.showMenu = false;
  });

});
```

So while switching to some other file the menu should hide ideally. But it didn't happen so.

Comment: How do you show menu on click?

Comment: using ng-click ..

`<div ng-click="showMenu = !showMenu" class="btn btn-navbar">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> 
</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you show your menu. With this code:

```
<div ng-click="showMenu=!showMenu" class="btn btn-navbar"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
```

you change `showMenu` property of the *child scope*. This `showMenu` is not the same as `$rootScope.showMenu`. For this reason when you change `$rootScope.showMenu` in `$routeChangeStart` it doesn't effect child scope property. Instead you should do something like this:

```
<div ng-click="toggleMenuBar()" class="btn btn-navbar"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.toggleMenuBar = function() {
    $rootScope.showMenu = !$rootScope.showMenu; 
};
```